# create an internal mixed protocol loadbalancer in Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I'm trying to create an internal mixed protocol loadbalancer in Azure AKS (tried 1.15.5, 1.15.7 and 1.16.4) using this yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-mixed-protocols: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  name: consullb
spec:
  ports:
        - port: 8500
          targetPort: 8500
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8400
          targetPort: 8400
          name: rpc
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8301
          targetPort: 8301
          name: serflan-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8302
          targetPort: 8302
          name: serfwan-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8300
          targetPort: 8300
          name: server
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8600
          targetPort: 8600
          name: consuldns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 8301
          targetPort: 8301
          name: serflan-udp
          protocol: UDP
        - port: 8302
          targetPort: 8302
          name: serfwan-udp
          protocol: UDP
        - port: 8600
          targetPort: 8600
          name: consuldns-udp
          protocol: UDP
  selector:
    component: consul-1582621245-consul    
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot create an external load balancer with mix protocols
```

I tested two different clusters one with the Standard SKU and one with the Basic SKU.

Anything I'm missing here? Or could someone point me other aspects to try/troubleshoot?

Comment: what happens if you remove the internal annotation?

Comment: same result :-(

Comment: Did you ever find out anything about this? I'm having the same issues with an external load balancer. It looks like it is just not implemented, although they closed the github issues on it

Comment: Yes, i asked the guy who implemented it on azure. Turns out it was removed in a later release, since k8s just doesn't support it. I did not find out why it is not supported by k8s though. If somebody knows that I would like to learn that!